# Increasing elements in list c#

Tags: c#, list

I have a study assignment, it says that if the list contains 0, then all its items must increase by 100, otherwise they are replaced by The absolute value of a number. The second part works fine, but when the number increases by 100, it somehow doesn't take negative values into account. Maybe there is another way to make it right?

```
int i = 0;
List<int> S = new List<int> { 1, 2, -5, -9, 10, 0, -45, 24, 54, 80, -12, -15 };
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", S));
while (i < S.Count) 
{
     if (S[i] == 0)
     {
            S = S.ConvertAll(i => 100 + i);
     }
```

[increasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9DvN.png)

[image]

Comment: When a question receives suggestions for improvement, please don't just delete it and start a new one, like you did with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67415494). Instead, improve the existing question. Please note that if you create a lot of poorly-received questions, you'll eventually be prevented from asking new ones.

Comment: As for "it somehow doesn't take negative values into account" - where do you believe you are *trying* to take that into account?

Comment: S = S.ConvertAll(i => 100 + i); here i thought it would count the negative numbers, but it didn't.

Comment: That's going to increase every value by 100. So -5 will be 95 in the new list.

Comment: @Maze `if (S[i] < 0) S[i] = (S[i] * -1) + 100;`

Comment: (The output you've shown as a screenshot - which would be better as *text* within the post - is not the output of the code you've shown, even after making it complete by incrementing `i` in the loop...)

Comment: Yes, It should be like that, but for some reason it doesn't work that way. It just -5+100=105

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xFMZ0S

Comment: @JonSkeet actually it is.

Comment: What happens if the list contains multiple zeroes?

Comment: @JonasH It doesn't matter how many zeroes contains the list. The assignment says that if there is zero. Thus, the number will be increased only 1 time.

Comment: @RandRandom thanks.                 if (S.Contains(0))                {                 S = S.ConvertAll(i => i + 100);                } Works as it should

Comment: I guess what you are doing wrong is, since you are using a loop `while (i < S.Count)` your if statment will be false on the first index `S[0] == 1` so NOT `0`, now you will most likely absolute the numbers so the `-5` on index `2` will get `5` - than your while loop continues till you hit the index with `0` and the previously converted `5` will then end up at `105`

Comment: @RandRandom yea, probably you're right. I changed to if (S.Contains(0)) and it works as it should. Thanks.

Comment: @Maze: No, it really doesn't. Here's a genuinely complete example: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/0e3c191baa1223285690ece2bd4d32b6. The second line of output is 101,102,95,91,110,100,55,124,154,180,88,85, which is not the same as your screenshot. This is why you should really, really provide a [mcve], and make sure that the output you show is the output from that code. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: As a general tip, you have two different `i` variables (one at the top, one in the lambda). This is very likely to cause confusion in which `i` is being referenced in `100 + i`? Try to keep variable names unique to prevent this confusion.

Comment: Should we propose a badge on meta "Thought to know better than Jon Skeet within one hour of joining SO" :)

Comment: @ChrisWesseling :D idk, but I really checked code and after that made that screenshot. It was from the same code as I posted earlier.

Comment: @Maze: Then there must have been other relevant code which you *didn't* post. Again, that's why it's such a problem to only post a snippet of code, instead of the complete code. (Your code doesn't even contain the closing brace for the while loop.) It's really hard for anyone to help when we can only see half of the code that affects the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are allowed to use System.Linq;

```
List<int> S = new List<int> { 1, 2, -5, -9, 10, 0, -45, 24, 54, 80, -12, -15 };
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", S));
    while (S.Any(x => x == 0))
    {
        S = S.ConvertAll(x => x += 100);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", S));
    }
```

The Output is:

```
1,2,-5,-9,10,0,-45,24,54,80,-12,-15
101,102,95,91,110,100,55,124,154,180,88,85
```

Comment: Notice that if you add `-100` to the list the output will be different, if desired or not I don't know.

Comment: The while loop is for that. As long as the list contains a 0, all elements will be +100. Otherwise, it would be a single line code @RandRandom

Answer (score -1):

```
int i = 0;
        List<int> S = new List<int> { 1, 2, -5, -9, 10, 0, -45, 24, 54, 80, -12, -15 };
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", S));
        while (i < S.Count) 
        {
            if (S.Contains(0))
            {
                S = S.ConvertAll(i => i + 100);
            }
            else
            {
                S = S.Select(i => Math.Abs(i)).ToList();
            }
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", S));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

the output is:

```
1,2,-5,-9,10,0,-45,24,54,80,-12,-15
101,102,95,91,110,100,55,124,154,180,88,85
```

So it works.
And if I don't have 0

```
1,2,-5,-9,10,12,-45,24,54,80,-12,-15
1,2,5,9,10,12,45,24,54,80,12,15
```

Comment: I sill would question, why the `while (i < S.Count)` ? Do you know the implication of the while loop? In what cases what happens? eg. do you know how your code behaves on various inputs ? See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kJEvGV

Comment: The `while` loop is unnecessary as OP's explanation does not include _repeated_ increases by 100. _However_, if you assume your goal of repeatedly increasing by 100 as long as any element is 0, then your code has a massive flaw: you prematurely make absolute values before you know the whole list and therefore if you still need to increment by 100. This is important for negative numbers. The order of operations matters, because `Math.Abs(-15 + 100) == 85 != 115 == Math.Abs(-15) + 100`.

Comment: @RandRandom hmm.. Now I see where I was wrong. I removed    while  and int i in the start and it works the same as before. Also i checked your link and tried to do it with and without while and now I see the difference.